# Simple Sort by dropdown on a custom wp_query CPT

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a basic archive feed.

I am trying to add a simple dropdown sort by form, that allows me to sort the results by date, title and popularity...

I kind of have it, but it's not quite working as I expected.

I have a dropdown, that 'onchange' grabs the value of the option, and adds it to the URL.  By setting the value to ?orderby=date&order=DESC it works...

However, it reloads the page (which is fine) and doesn't save the value of the option selected... so the dropdown field doesn't show the value selected...

It also doesn't remove the value if I select a different one.  So it will append ?orderby=date&order=ASC on the end of orderby=date&order=DESC if selected.  And will keep doing that, which causes issues.

Thirdly, 'Views' doesn't seem to work, not sure what the value should be to filter by how many people have viewed the page (is that even possible?!)

```
if ( have_posts() ) : 
    echo '<div class="posts-query">';?>
        <div id="sortby"> SORT BY: &nbsp;
        <select class="dropdown-class" name="sort-posts" id="sortbox" onchange="document.location.href=location.href+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
        <option disabled>Sort by</option>
        <option value="?orderby=date&order=DESC">Newest</option>
        <option value="?orderby=date&order=ASC">Oldest</option>
        <option value="?orderby=title&order=ASC">A-Z Asc</option>
        <option value="?orderby=title&order=DESC">A-Z Desc</option>
        <option value="?orderby=views&order=ASC">Views Asc</option>
            <option value="?orderby=views&order=DESC">Views Asc</option>
    </select>
</div>


<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>   
            <div class="query-post">
                <div class="posts-image">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail("thumbnail");?>
                </div>
                <div class="post-categories">
                    <?php $postType = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());
                    if ($postType) {
                    echo esc_html($postType->labels->singular_name);
                    } ?>
                </div>

                <div class="posts-title">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <h3> 
                            <?php the_title() ?>
                        </h3>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Is there a way to simply sort the WP_Query by date, title and views, and have it not only SAVE the selected result in the option dropdown as 'selected' but also have it remove the previous query if a new one is selected from the dropdown?

Comment: If you want an option to be pre-selected, then _you_ need to facilitate that, by adding the according attribute. If you don’t know how to do that in PHP based on a parameter that was passed to the script, please do some research (this is everything but a new topic.)

Comment: And the second problem could in this instance likely simply be fixed by manipulating `location.search` only, and not the complete URL.

Comment: Thanks.  I did numerous searches for this topic, and whilst I found various posts - none of them seemed to relate to my much more 'simple' approach.  All the ones I found were for sorting by custom fields.  Maybe I didn't search correctly.

Comment: Pre-selecting the option the user chose has nothing to do with filtering a WQ query specifically. You need to check which parameters were passed to your script, and then see which option matches those.

Comment: I see.  That's not something I know how to do, hence why I posted the Question hoping for a full answer.

Comment: you could also just put the full permalink into your values - that way you won't need to append. `<option value="<?php echo get_permalink();?>?orderby=title&order=DESC">A-Z Desc</option>` then tweak your js to take that on change. `get_permalink()` does not grab your parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who may be interested, I solved this using the following code:

```
<div id="sortby"> SORT BY: &nbsp;
        <select class="dropdown-class" name="sort-posts" id="sortbox" onchange="document.location.search=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
        <option disabled>Sort by</option>
        <option <?php if( isset($_GET["orderby"]) && trim($_GET["orderby"]) == 'date' && isset($_GET["order"]) && trim($_GET["order"]) == 'DESC' ){ echo 'selected'; } ?> value="?orderby=date&order=DESC">Newest</option>
        <option <?php if( isset($_GET["orderby"]) && trim($_GET["orderby"]) == 'date' && isset($_GET["order"]) && trim($_GET["order"]) == 'ASC' ){ echo 'selected'; } ?>  value="?orderby=date&order=ASC">Oldest</option>
        <option <?php if( isset($_GET["orderby"]) && trim($_GET["orderby"]) == 'title' && isset($_GET["order"]) && trim($_GET["order"]) == 'ASC' ){ echo 'selected'; } ?> value="?orderby=date&order=DESC" value="?orderby=title&order=ASC">A-Z Asc</option>
        <option <?php if( isset($_GET["orderby"]) && trim($_GET["orderby"]) == 'title' && isset($_GET["order"]) && trim($_GET["order"]) == 'DESC' ){ echo 'selected'; } ?>  value="?orderby=title&order=DESC">A-Z Desc</option>
        <option <?php if( isset($_GET["orderby"]) && trim($_GET["orderby"]) == 'views' && isset($_GET["order"]) && trim($_GET["order"]) == 'ASC' ){ echo 'selected'; } ?> value="?orderby=views&order=ASC">Views Asc</option>
        <option <?php if( isset($_GET["orderby"]) && trim($_GET["orderby"]) == 'views' && isset($_GET["order"]) && trim($_GET["order"]) == 'DESC' ){ echo 'selected'; } ?> value="?orderby=views&order=DESC">Views Desc</option>

        </select>
        </div>
```